# Solve $\sum_{i=1}^{200} {1\over{1+x_i}} =?$

Tags: polynomials, summation, fractions

$$ (x^{2}+x+1)^{100}=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^{2}+...+a_{199}x^{199}+a_{200}x^{200}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{200} {1\over{1+x_i}} =?$$
Can somebody help me? Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean $a_i$ instead of $x_i$ in the sum?

Comment: No. It's $x_{i}$ in the sum.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You haven't defined the $x_i$. Also, what are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: You forgot to mention what you have tried.

Comment: $x_{i}$ are the solution of the problem, $x_1 ,x_2...x_{200}$ . I tried to amplified each fraction for a common denominator. But I don't know what i can do to solve it after that

Comment: How $a_i$ and $x_i$ are related? Are they equal?

Comment: No. $a_i%$ is just the coefficients of the roots $x_i$

Comment: Is the question complete? It doesn't makes any sense.

Comment: How are $x_i$ defined? You didn't mention this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{200}\frac{1}{1+x_k}=100\left(\frac{1}{1+x_1}+\frac{1}{1+x_2}\right)=\frac{100(2+x_1+x_2)}{1+x_1+x_2+x_1x_2}=$$
$$=\frac{100(2-1)}{1-1+1}=100.$$

Comment: Can you explain me why is 100 * paranthesis?

Comment: @Andrew Because our polynomial has $100$ roots $x_1$ and $100$ roots $x_2$, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are roots of the polynomial $x^2+x+1$. You are welcome!